# Itertools product between list and df with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'dex', 'tru'],
                   'B': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']})
```

Which looks like:

```
     A
0  foo
1  bar
2  dex
3  tru
```

I also have the following list:

```
block_number = [1000, 2000]
```

I want the following output `new_df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'dex', 'tru', 'foo', 'bar', 'dex', 'tru'],
                   'B': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'],
                   'block_number': [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000]})
```

Which looks like:

```
     A    B  block_number
0  foo  abc          1000
1  bar  def          1000
2  dex  ghi          1000
3  tru  jkl          1000
4  foo  abc          2000
5  bar  def          2000
6  dex  ghi          2000
7  tru  jkl          2000
```

I basically need have each item in `my_list` per row on `df`, but do that for all the different items in my list.

```
from itertools import product

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    product(df.A, block_number), columns=["A", "block_number"]
).sort_values(by="block_number")

print(df_out)
```

from Andrej at [Multiply and repeat every row of df by n-item list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74072050/multiply-and-repeat-every-row-of-df-by-n-item-list) only gives me correct results for a single column `df`. What if my df has 2 or more (even thousands of columns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the keys parameter in `pd.concat()`

```
(pd.concat([df]*len(block_number),
keys = block_number,
names = ['block_number'])).reset_index(level=0)
```

Output:

```
   block_number    A    B
0          1000  foo  abc
1          1000  bar  def
2          1000  dex  ghi
3          1000  tru  jkl
0          2000  foo  abc
1          2000  bar  def
2          2000  dex  ghi
3          2000  tru  jkl
```

Comment: Had to add a `.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)` because some of the rows were duplicated (idk why), but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `itertools.product` which requires extracting each cell value in the dataframe, create a new dataframe with the final row count by concatentation, then assign block numbers by slice.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'dex', 'tru'],
                   'B': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']})

block_number = [1000, 2000]

new_df = pd.concat([df] * len(block_number), ignore_index=True)
new_df['block_number'] = block_number[0]
for i, num in enumerate(block_number[1:], 1):
    new_df.loc[i*len(df):(i+1)*len(df), 'block_number'] = num

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Your solution is giving me a `block_number` column with the same number for all rows, even though the A and B columns are correctly output.

Comment: I neglected to initialize block_number, but when fixed, the posted code will give you both 1000 and 2000 ranges. It starts with the same value for the entire block_number column but then the for loop assigns new block numbers to specific slices.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for any number of columns:

```
import itertools
df_new = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*[df.values,block_number]))
df_new = df_new[0].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns = lambda x: chr(x+65)).assign(
    block_number = df_new[1]).sort_values(by="block_number").reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
     A    B  block_number
0  foo  abc          1000
1  bar  def          1000
2  dex  ghi          1000
3  tru  jkl          1000
4  foo  abc          2000
5  bar  def          2000
6  dex  ghi          2000
7  tru  jkl          2000
```